# JavaAgentDetector error while deploying to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jhipster

I have a Java 8, Spring boot application that has an embedded Tomcat (it is actually a JHipster 3.0.0 monolithic app). I want to deploy it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

My approaches:

1. On a Java environment, with a Procfile.
2. On a Tomcat environment, with a Procfile.
3. On a Java environment, without a Procfile.
4. On a Tomcat environment, without a Procfile.

No matter the approach I always get this error.

[image]

I am not using ever in my project that JavaAgentDetector.class that Elastic Beanstalk fails to inflate.

[image]

Of course, when I execute that .war locally there are no problems.
Thoughts?

Comment: If you are using embedded Tomcat then you should only be looking at the Java environment.  In order to understand your application in greater detail, a sample project on GitHub would be most helpful.  I also recommend the Docker environment on Elastic Beanstalk.  See this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What made the trick: I finally deployed my app on a Tomcat environment without a Procfile. The error was a caps lock difference between my pom.xml and my application-prod.properties in the name of the database.

Answer (score 0):

could be a difference in your production profile and dev profile?